# Mixed static/dynamic animations in Unity3D >=5.0

Tags: animation, dynamic, unity-game-engine, static

Is it possible to combine animations created within the unity editor with scripted animation, e.g. I want a camera to rotate 90 degrees on Y axis and move to a point V in the duration of 3 seconds. Everything but the target point vector V should be animated statically, but the vector V should be given at runtime through a script.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: I think you would be able to do that by controlling the blend of different animations with animation controller parameters, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: This would only allow me to blend between 2 static animations, AFAIK. It would allow me to "tween" between two vectors V1 and V2, but both would have to be given at compile time. I want to give V at runtime.

Comment: Well, you could, theoretically, provide the V1, V2 and V3 so that all reasonable values of V would be in between, but it does sound ugly.

Comment: What about blending a purely static animation with a purely dynamic one?